# Android Studio fail to add layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

According to Google Guide ( https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui ) the screen should now look like the first image but in my case, the screen is somewhat like the second image. Don't know what mistake I made. 
Please do help

first image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVm0K.png)

Second image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHhYM.png)

Comment: make it into relative layout

Comment: please share your XML code

Comment: check the error by clicking on the red icon(exclamation) in second image

Comment: if it says rendering problem share your gradle code